# how to change home page logo imge in peopletools8.54

Tags: peoplesoft

everone 
    how to change home page logo image in pepleSoft ?
    I had created new "PT_ORACLELOGO_CSS" image in Application Designer,and then restart app server,web Server and purge app cache,but it still show  oracle logo。
    this is our peoplesoft environment ：
    peopleTools release is 8.54.08 & 
    Application Release:9.20.00.000

Answer (score 0):

**FLUID BRANDING (8.54):**

I had to do this just the other day, real easy to accomplish.
Navigate to Main Menu > PeopleTools > Portal > Branding > Branding Objects then click on the 'Image' tab. Click 'Upload Image Object' then upload your image. Then you will want to open up App Designer: App Designer > File > Open > Page > Select: PTNUI_LP_HEADER. Double click on the square button right next to the Cancel button. When the properties box opens click the label tab and under 'Label Image' upload your image. Click OK then save the page and your image should appear in the header. [Here is some documentation](http://pe0ples0ft.blogspot.com/2015/06/peopletools-854-branding-part-5a-fluid.html) I found that could help you out a lot.

**BRANDING (8.54):**

[Follow along with this article, it is very good at describing the steps you need to take to change the page logo.](http://pe0ples0ft.blogspot.com/2014/11/peopletools-854-branding-part-1.html)

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your anser.According to your method, I tried, but did not changed.or need other set up?
   In "PS_HOMEwebserv\peoplesoft\applications\peoplesoft\PORTAL.war\ps\cache\",I found the logo image,then replace the new logo , finally it's ok.

Comment: @DillonMa Apollogies to you, I gave you the steps to change the logo for _fluid_ pages. I have updated my answer with an article that is very well written and should give you a lot of knowledge on branding your site.